# Loss of chart when exporting data in DynamicModule

Tags: bugs, export, dynamic

**Bug fixed in V 10.2**

---

In `DynamicModule`, the result is to show a panel with a flowchart and a `Piechart`. But when I export the dynamic result in a CSV file, the `Piechart` will no longer work. But the flowchart is still working.

To be more precise for discription of the question, I would like to mean that the `Piechart` works well, [image]

but when I clicked the `Export`, the `Piechart` will look like this.

[image]

Here, I have simplified the code uploaded to faciliate the comprehension of the code. Thanks.

```
DynamicModule[{FlowratePAPC = 100, TemperaturePAPC = 350, 
heatPAPCsensible, heatbalance},
heatbalance = {Button["Primary Air", 
 CreateDialog[
  Column[{Row[{Style["Flow rate(kg/hr)", Bold, 14], 
      InputField[Dynamic[FlowratePAPC], 
       ContinuousAction -> True]}], 
    Row[{Style["Flow temperature(\[Degree]C)", Bold, 14], 
      InputField[Dynamic[TemperaturePAPC], 
       ContinuousAction -> True]}]}]]] -> 
Style["Precalcinator", Bold, 14]};
Panel[Column[{LayeredGraphPlot[heatbalance, VertexLabeling -> True], 
Dynamic@PieChart3D[{Legended[heatPAPCsensible[], 
    Style["PCPA Sensible", Bold, 12, Black]]}],
Button["Export", 
 Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", 
   "Cement project data.csv"], {heatPAPCsensible[]}], 
 Method -> "Queued"]}]],
 Initialization :> ({heatPAPCsensible[] := 
 ThermodynamicData["Air", 
   "Enthalpy", {"Temperature" -> 
     Quantity[TemperaturePAPC, "Kelvins"], 
    "Pressure" -> Quantity[101325, "Pascals"]}]*
  Quantity[FlowratePAPC, "kg"]/Quantity[1, "hour"]})]
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. I tried running your code, and it seems to work as far as I can tell. Can you please clarify what your problem is exactly?

Comment: @MarcoB The problem is that once I click the Export button, the 3D piechart will no longer display. I do not know the reason.

Comment: Aha, unfortunately I am unable to reproduce the behavior you describe on Mathematica 10.1.0. The pie chart still works even after pressing the export button. The problem may be version or system dependent.

Comment: @aha, please specify your Mathematica version and OS

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries Platform:Windows7 Prefessionnel, Mathematica:10.0. Thanks.

Comment: @aha 10.0.0, 10.0.1 or 10.0.2?

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries, 10.0.2.0

Comment: It works for me on 10.0.2.0 (Mac OSX), except when I give bad input (e.g. Flow rate = 100, temp = 3500), I get `Missing[NotAvailable]` for `heatPAPCsensible[]`.  On such bad input the chart disappears. Is that what you mean by "piechart will no longer work"?   ("Not working" is not a very good description of what appears wrong, BTW.) Try displaying the value of `heatPAPCsensible[]` and see what you get.

Comment: @MichaelE2, Thanks for you remind, I have re-precised the problem I had in the main Question part.

Comment: Using your latest posted code and running V10.1 on OS X 1010.2, I still find absolutely no problem after exporting a CSV file. Your simplified code is unable to produce the problem you are experiencing on my system.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks for you response , I have contacted the technical support of Mma. They said it is related to the version problem that I should update to 10.2.

Answer (score 1):

> I have contacted the technical support of MMA. They said it is related to the version problem that I should update to 10.2.
>
> – Aha Jul 27 at 9:02